# How to convert unix-timestamp to d-m-Y in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

In a php-script I do a query for reading record from my sql-database. In every -record there is a datefield 'birthdate'. This datefield is a bigint typefield. The result of my script is a unix-timestamp and a empty field. What is wrong? See my code.
The result:

```
Birthdate         Birthdate
157766400         01-01-1970
410227200         01-01-1970
and so on

...

<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=local-db;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    $sql = "SELECT birthdate FROM wp_pdb WHERE 1;
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . 
        $row['birthdate'] . "</td><td>" . 
        date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row['birthdate'])) . "</td><td>" . 
        "<br /> ";
}
?>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this?

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%d-%m-%Y') AS 'date'
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use strtotime - the number you're getting is already parsed that way. Just do

```
date('d-m-Y', $row['birthdate'])
```